# Mssql loop with UNION t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops

I just use Mssql procedure given at this site [Using loop with UNION t-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16802105/using-loop-with-union-t-sql) to build my own loop procedure. 
When I'm executing this code:

```
SELECT      '[hpsdb].[dbo].[' + r.CAMP_TABLE_NAME + ']' 
FROM        [hpsdb].[dbo].[T_HPS_CAMPAIGN_TASK] t
LEFT JOIN   [hpsdb].[dbo].[T_HPS_CAMPAIGN_TABLE_REF] r ON (r.CAMPAIGN_ID=t.CAMPAIGN_ID)
WHERE       SKILL_ID = 2
```

it is returning two tables name. But when I executing this procedure it is never end.

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @DSQL VARCHAR(4000)
SET @DSQL = ''

DECLARE cTableList CURSOR FOR
SELECT      '[hpsdb].[dbo].[' + r.CAMP_TABLE_NAME + ']' 
FROM        [hpsdb].[dbo].[T_HPS_CAMPAIGN_TASK] t
LEFT JOIN   [hpsdb].[dbo].[T_HPS_CAMPAIGN_TABLE_REF] r ON (r.CAMPAIGN_ID=t.CAMPAIGN_ID)
WHERE       SKILL_ID = 2

OPEN cTableList

FETCH NEXT FROM cTableList INTO @TableName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @DSQL = @DSQL + 'SELECT ID FROM ' + @TableName + ' UNION ALL '
END

CLOSE cTableList
DEALLOCATE cTableList

-- Remove the last UNION ALL
IF LEN(@DSQL) > 11 SET @DSQL = LEFT(@DSQL,LEN(@DSQL) - 11)

EXEC (@DSQL)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need another `FETCH NEXT` statement within your WHILE LOOP to keep moving through the cursor otherwise you will just stay on the first record and the value of `@@FETCH_STATUS` will never change.

```
FETCH NEXT FROM cTableList INTO @TableName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF @DSQL = ''
      SET @DSQL = 'SELECT ID FROM [' + @TableName + ']'
    ELSE
      SET @DSQL = @DSQL + ' UNION ALL SELECT ID FROM [' + @TableName + ']'
    FETCH NEXT FROM cTableList INTO @TableName
END
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I added this line error appear:  `Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '(name of my table from CURSOR)'`

Comment: The tables names in @TableName may have special characters so I added brackets around the value. In addition, you original loop would have had a trailing 'UNION ALL' at the end of your SQL statement so I modified it to check if it was the first time and do something different. This means that you can remove the IF LEN statement after your loop.

Answer (score 0):

FETCH NEXT FROM cTableList INTO @TableName
must be used within loop. otherwise @@fetch_status will remain 0 which will cause infinity loop

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Look into how to format your answers, to make them easier to read in the future!