# How to delete last "union" while using fetch cursor

Tags: sql-server, cursor, fetch, union

I want to union queries with many parameters, with this similar code

```
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
 set @query = @query + 'select ' + @temp + ' from table_A' + char(13) + 'union' + char(13)
fetch next from cur into @temp
end
```

the issue, is how to delete last union?

Comment: You write code. You can add a little complexity to your logic and check for your last loop iteration. You can change your logic to add "union " + #temp (opposite to what you have now). Or you can simply remove the last x (you count them - not my job) characters after loop ends.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I got similar things in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19427217/mssql-loop-with-union-t-sql. Problem solved, thanks !