# Loop through list of table names to query each and union results

Tags: t-sql, while-loop, variable-assignment

I am trying to union single row results from queries of various tables. These results include the name of the table queried and the distinct count of an id column. I am trying to avoid manually writing numerous queries and unions by using the values in a "list" instead. If written manually, the queries would have the following pattern.

```
UNION SELECT *, 'viewName' = Organization FROM viewName
UNION
```

When I tried to do this, I got a T-SQL syntax error related to the way the variable is declared that I could not resolve.

I do not understand the following post well enough to tell if it is relevant to my problem. I don't see why T-SQL has to generate T-SQL script there or if I need to do that here.

[Using loop with UNION t-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16802105/using-loop-with-union-t-sql)

In the code below, I use [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589214/t-sql-looping-through-an-array-of-known-values) as a template and

1. create a table
2. create a table variable with declare @ids table(..
3. assign values to this variable
4. loop through these values and in each iteration insert the value and a count(distinct ...) from a value-named view into the table I created earlier.

I am trying to accomplish this with the following code/query, but get the error:

```
Must declare the scalar variable "@id".  For the @id in the highlighted lines below.
```

I tried declaring outside the loop, but that didn't work.

Declaring the variable as varchar got the error

```
Must declare the table variable "@id".
```

Microsoft learn says that to set a variable as the result of a query, it must be a scalar OR the query must only return one row. I cannot imagine how the latter is not the case because the identity variable @idx and counter/iterator @i each have unique values.

**Setting A Value in a Transact SQL Variable:**
-- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/variables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#setting-a-value-in-a-transact-sql-variable

How can I modify this code, so it inserts the line returned by SELECT @id ... FROM @id into the table specified?

1. create a table

```
CREATE TABLE [PaCountsByOrg](
    [Organization] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [PA Counts] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

2. create a table variable with declare @ids table(..

```
declare @ids table(idx int identity(1,1), id [varchar](50))
```

3. Assign values to this variable. I am testing with single value before I add them all

```
insert into @ids (id)
    SELECT 'vwBHS' 
    --UNION
    --SELECT 'vwChap' UNION
    --SELECT 'vwCenCalAdventist' UNION
    --...
```

4. loop through these values and in each iteration insert the value and a count(distinct ...) from a value-named view into the table I created earlier.

```
declare @i int
declare @cnt int
 
select @i = min(idx) - 1, @cnt = max(idx) from @ids
 
while @i < @cnt
begin
     select @i = @i + 1
 
     --declare @id = select id from @ids where idx = @i
     declare @id table(id [varchar](50))
    select @id =  id from @ids where idx = @i
 
        --SELECT @EmpIDVariable = MAX(EmployeeID)
        --FROM HumanResources.Employee;
 
     INSERT INTO [PaCountsByOrg]
       SELECT @id AS [Organization], COUNT(DISTINCT [PseudoAddressID]) AS [PA Counts] 
        FROM @id
 
end
```

I get the error:

```
Must declare the scalar variable "@id".
```

Comment: You have a table variable `@ids` and a scalar variable `@id`. Did you intend `FROM @id` to be `FROM @ids`?

Comment: You'll need to use _dynamic SQL_ in order to take a table name from a table or variable and use it as the name of a table in a `from` clause. Have a look at [`sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and [`QuoteName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).